# Pyspark with sklearn and dataframe types conversion

Tags: python, pyspark, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to use sklearn with pyspark but I'm having some performance issues. Lets say I have a dataset that have already went through a pipeline where features were vectorized and normalized. In order to use sklearn I'll either have to provide the algorithm an array or a pandas dataframe. Considering the size of my dataset (2.8M + and should grow bigger soon), converting the train set to pandas is painstakingly slow  so I'm using a numpy approach:

```
train =  np.array(train.select('features').collect()).squeeze()
```

This is relatively slow as I need to use collect to push data back to the driver. Is there any other approach that would be faster and better? Additionally, due to the nature of the problem I'm currently handling my scoring function in a non-standard way:

```
def score (fitmodel, test):
   predY = fitmodel.score_samples(test)
   return np.full((1, len(predY)), np.mean(predY)).transpose()
```

The idea is to compute the average of the predictions and then return an array where this result is replicated as many times as the number of records tested. E.g. if my testset has 450 records I'll return an array shaped (450,1) where all 450 records have the same value (average of the predictions). Although slow, so far so good and everything works as intended. My problem is that I need to proceed with the testing by doing this multiple times (changing the test set) and append the results to a single array in order to evaluate the model's performance later. My code:

```
for _ in tdqm(range(450, 800)):
    #Get group #X
    _test = df.where(col('index') == _) #Get a different "chunk" of the dataset each iteration
    _test.coalesce(2) 
    #Apply pipeline with transforms
    test = pipelineModel.transform(_test)
    y_test = np.array(test.select('label').collect())
    x_test = np.array(test.select('features').collect()).squeeze()
    pred = newScore(x_test, model)
    
    if(_ == (450)): #First run
        trueY = y_test
        predY = pred
    else:
        trueY = np.append(trueY, y_test)
        predY = np.append(predY, pred)
```

Briefly, I grab a specific portion of the dataset, test it and then i want to append both the predictions and "true" label for later evaluation. My main problem here is that doing 2 collects and a np.append takes a long time and I need to find an alternative. Testing the entire test set (about 400k entries) takes me ~1min but with all these in place it increases the time to 2h20min.
On top of this I have to convert the array back to a pyspark dataframe to use the mllib evaluation functions which adds a bit more time to the process.

With all this being said, could anyone point me in a direction where I could accomplish this in a more efficient way? Maybe there is another way to use spark and sklearn ?

Comment: The 'efficient' approach is to avoid sklearn and use what is offered by pyspark ml.

Comment: That is not the answer I was expecting. Obviously I use pyspark ml whenever possible but as you know some models are not available yet.